# Zend Framework 2 - handling form actions

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, zend-form2

In Zend Framework 2, I've created a class that extends `Zend\Form\Form` called `MyForm`.

In the `indexAction` of one Controller class, I'll initialize `MyForm` like this:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
     $form = new MyForm('my-name');
     $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
     return $viewModel;
 }
```

Then in the corresponding view, I basically just do

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form);
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

This all works, but you may have noticed that the action for the form is missing.

I have tried to add the action like this in the view:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Index', 'action' => 'go')));
```

Then in the go action inside my IndexController I just have this for testing:

```
    public function goAction()
    {
        die('huh');
    }
```

This did not work at all, I always land at the form view (== index action) again. Why is the go action never executed?

I also know that I could either hardcode the action attribute and let a segment route handle the processing, or I could even define an own route for that.

In what cases form actions should get their own route?
In what cases form actions should be handled using a segment route?
In what cases form actions should be handled like in my example?

If there are no hard rules for this: What intention do the different approaches communicate?

Is it also possible to add form actions in the controller instead of the view?

Comment: does the `<form>` tag in the HTML source show the action that you set?

Comment: @TimFountain If I hardcode the value yes, if I use the `$this->url(NULL, array('controller'=>'Index', 'action' => 'go')` approach I think it points to the current route's index action (which is also the default one). What is the action attribute supposed to show?

Comment: Ah - why are you passing NULL as the first parameter to the URL helper? That should be the route name

Comment: @TimFountain In a ZF2 book I own that way is used to basically bypass the need to set up a route specific for the form action and directly tell the framework what controller & action to use. I think this could be an advantage, but also maybe make things less clear, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing on from the comments: That's not how the URL helper works - if you omit the first parameter, the current route is used instead. That's probably why you're not getting the form action you expect.

Personally, I always specify the route name when using the URL helper - makes things clearer.

Comment: That makes sense, but even when I do it like that in the view `    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('myroute', array('action' => 'go')));`it won't work. The form action also just points to the current URL. Digging into the routes now.

Comment: Found the problem! After all, this was making the problems: I had the default action defined like this: `'controller' => 'Mymodule\Controller/Index',`. That way, the framework does not now the namespace the action is located in. The right way to do it is `'__NAMESPACE__' => 'Mymodule\Controller', 'controller' => 'Index',` (or at least it works for me that way). Now I could even pass `NULL`if I wanted to ;-) Thanks for your help!